# Multiple series for multiple tags in one Grafana graph

Tags: graph, metrics, grafana, opentsdb

Is it possible to create a graph in Grafana using OpenTSDB as data source where it has multiple metrics and each metric has multiple values for the same tag?

Say I have `load.average.1m` and `load.average.5m`, and each of the two has host tag as `host1`, `host2`.

Is there a sane way to make the graph to display `load.average.1m` and `load.average.5m` for `host1` and also `load.average.1m` and `load.average.5m` for `host2`? All I am getting now is `host1` and `host2` repeated twice on the graph legend, so it's 4 legend items for 2 things.